# Scrolling background image to reset when position = height Jquery

Tags: jquery, function, scroll

I'm trying to produce a jQuery animation which scrolls a background image until it gets to the end of the image and then starts again.

I've managed to get the scroll working & calculated the height of the background image by mixing various code from here but when I try and combine the two it stops working.

I'm not overly family with javascript so don't really know what's going on!

Code Below:

```
<div class="animateIcon">
    <img src="images/spacer.png" width="144" height="167" class="animation" />
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 var scrollSpeed = 100;
 var current = 0;
 var step = 167; // How many pixels to move per step
 var direction = 'v';// set the direction

 $.fn.getBgImage = function (callback) {
     var height = 0;
     var path = $(this).css('background-image').replace('url', '').replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace('"', '').replace('"', '');
     var tempImg = $('<img />');
     tempImg.hide(); //hide image
     tempImg.bind('load', callback);
     $('body').append(tempImg); // add to DOM before </body>
     tempImg.attr('src', path);
     $('#tempImg').remove(); //remove from DOM
 };

 $(".animation").getBgImage(function () {

     var restartPosition = -($(this).height());

 });

 function bgscroll() {

     //Go to next pixel row.

     current -= step;



     //If at the end of the image, then go to the top.

     if (current <= restartPosition) {

         current = 0;

     }

     // move the background with backgrond-position css properties
     $('.animation').css("background-position", (direction == 'v') ? "0 " + current + "px" : current + "px 0");

 }

 //Calls the scrolling function repeatedly
 setInterval(bgscroll, scrollSpeed);

 });
```

It appears to break when I add this code, but can't figure out why:

```
     //If at the end of the image, then go to the top.

     if (current <= restartPosition) {

         current = 0;

     }
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried running the code, but it looks like `restartPosition` is not in the same scope as `bgscroll`.

Try adding `var restartPosition;` at the top with your other global variables, and change `var restartPosition = -($(this).height());` to `restartPosition = -($(this).height());`

Comment: Thanks, the script now works but instead of taking the height of the background image, 'this' is taking the height of the browser